# php get facebook page status 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-302

This is not duplicate because I made curl follow redirects and the output is 302 http status code

I have this code

```
<?php 

$url="http://www.facebook.com/thisfburldoesnotexist";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $httpCode;
curl_close($handle);
?>
```

to grab the status code of some pages, but when I try to get the status of this `http://www.facebook.com/thisfburldoesnotexist` the response is 302, but Chrome report http 404 when debugging
[image]

how can I get the actual 404 reported in Chrome?

If I check the url with this tool http://www.websitepulse.com/help/tools.php it reports what I want: 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, when you request that non-existent page, facebook responds with a page with status code 302 or 307. Then, it **redirects to another page** with status code 404.

So you need to add this curl option so curl will follow that redirect, and eventually land on the 404 page.

`curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`

By default, this parameter is set to `0`, so, just like in your case, it does not follow the redirect and the response you get is just the 302 or 307 or whatever facebook decides to send as a **first** response. By setting it to `1` it will follow the redirect.

more info here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html

just noticed, you can actually see what im saying in your screenshot. the first response you are getting **is** a 307.

Chrome browser and that tool on that website do honor the redirect request, curl does not unless configured as described above.

Comment: If I ask you to get the 404 code with php, how would you do that in PHP? I've tried in so many ways but didn`t worked for me...